# long double to string

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developping in C++, using the Qt framework.

I need to convert a `long double` value into a string (ideally a `QString`, but could be something else).

So far, I always used QString::number() for numerical->string conversion, but there is no overloading for the `long double`type.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QString has a static function to construct a QString from a std::string, so wheaties' answer could be rewritten as:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <QString>
...
QString qStringFromLongDouble(const long double myLongDouble)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << myLongDouble;

  return QString::fromStdString(ss.str());
}
```

Comment: Also possible is `return QString(ss.str().c_str());`

Comment: @Adam: `QString::fromStdString()` can use the `std::string`'s size() to avoid counting the length of the string. If you pass a bare `const char*` to `QString()` then it has to recalculate what is already known.

Comment: right, good to know.  I usually get to avoid all of this with `QString("%1").arg(n)` but it doesn't handle long double :)

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
string convert(long double myLongDouble) {
    stringstream blah;
    blah << myLongDouble;

    return blah.str();
}
```

With Templates:

```
template<class T> string convert(T _input) {
    stringstream blah;
    blah << _input;

    return blah.str();
}
```

Comment: @Mike: better to assume `using std::string; using std::stringstream;`

Comment: Actually, I use `std::string` and `std::stringstream`.  I'm not a big fan of `using`; like `#include`, it puts important information out of view of most of the source (i.e. `#include` and `using` statements are usually at the start of the source file, so you have to look back from wherever you are to gain context).  I just brought this up because there are a *lot* of programmers that put `using namespace std;` in *all* their code and assume everyone else does as well.

Answer (score 0):

Boost has `lexical_cast` for this purpose.  It pretty much wraps the solution wheaties gave into a class template.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked is not complete, it will save it with only 6 decimal digits.
It should be like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

QString longDoubleToString(long double value)
    {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1) << value;
    return QString::fromStdString(stream.str());
    }
```