# Output long double to console

Tags: c++, qt, long-double

I tried to output a `long double` to the console directly using `qDebug()` and indirectly via `QString::number()` but both do not accept `long double`.

Is it true that there is no easy way of printing a `long double` floating point number to the console using Qt? Why?!

Comment: Since a `long double` does not need to take any more space then a `double` they may have felt it was pointless.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  That depends on your platform.  16-bit Windows uses 80 bits for `long double` and 64 bits for `double`.  I wouldn't be surprised if there are other examples.

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326850/long-double-to-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no overarching reason. At least as of Qt 5.6, nobody bothered to implement it. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your own overload of `operator<<()`:

```
QDebug& operator<<(QDebug& d, long double f)
{
    return d << static_cast<double>(f);
}
```

This won't show you any extra precision, of course, but may be what you need.

Be aware, however, that a future version of Qt might implement such a function, putting you in violation of the One-Definition Rule.  To avoid this, you should guard it with an appropriate `#if` test for the exact Qt version (or range of versions) that you have verified do not provide a conflicting definition.  Also, please consider [contributing your implementation to Qt](https://www.qt.io/contribute/).